# canvas.captureStream(frameRate) cannot obtain a continuous data stream when the canvas is not animated

Tags: vuejs2

I want captureStream to continuously capture data when there is no animation on my canvas, but it only starts working when there is animation update

I tried to use ffmpeg instead of captureStream, but the usage scenario does not support it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.